# How to save each file in a for loop using matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, save, hdf

I have three files named as modis1.hdf, modis2.hdf and modis3.hdf in one folder. I am able to read files individually using my command.

```
for i=1:3 or for i=1

lst_try=['D:\lst2016\lst_try\modis',num2str(i),'.hdf'];

lst_3(:,:,:,:,i)=hdfread(lst_try, 'MODIS_Grid_Daily_1km_LST', 'Fields', 'LST_Day_1km', 'Box',{[76.83        77.34], [28.88        28.41]});

end
```

I want to save each file separately either in hdf format or ascii format. Therefore, i was using command

```
save(lst_try,'lst_3','-hdf')
```

But not able to save file individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make individual names for every savefile.

If i understood right, you are having different data separated in a matrix dimension. Just separated these data and save it individually.

```
%do whatever you need to do

partname='myfile'

for ii=1:3,

  var_temp=lst_3(:,:,:,:,ii); %split the interesting part of you data. 

  name=[partname num2str(ii)]; %make a individual name
  save(name,'var_temp','-ascii') %saving by separated names

end
```

Note that i used `'-ascii'` option, as the [`save` function](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) does not takes the *hdf* format. This comes with a drawback, you can save only matrix of size `(N,M)`.

The `ascii` option cannot take 3D data.

Comment: The problem is rather that he saves all data in one variable and tries to save this at once "individually"

Comment: @Irreducible Indeed. I was imagining that the analysis was done inside the same loop. I will make a correction indeed.

Comment: @Guto Thanks for helping, but matlab is showing this error:myfile

Error using save
Unknown command option.

Error in stackoverflow (line 15)
  save(name,'var_temp','-hdf') %saving by separated names

Comment: @VaishaliJain  `-hdf` is indeed not a format recognized on `save`. You could use [`imwrite`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html). There is [this](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/exporting-to-hierarchical-data-format-hdf4-files.html) also. The last seems more like your case.

Comment: @VaishaliJain I can take a look, but if the problem turns into a save in hdf4 problem, i cannot help much, beyond have experience reading Matlab Manuals :P . HDF5  have a `hdf5write` function. If we got stuck in the saving hdf format, it's better to ask a new question specifically about that.

Comment: okay, can we save the files in simple matrix only? hdf format is not needed in the output files.

Comment: @VaishaliJain I updated the question! :D, check if it fits your case.

Comment: @Guto this error is coming, Warning: Attempt to write an unsupported data type to an ASCII file.
 Variable 'var_temp' not written to file.          My input file is in hdf format and output file is 5D matrix

Comment: @VaishaliJain well, a 5D matrix is not supported as I wrote. Go with .mat or find a more suitable format for you. The procedure is the same. With .mat you can save even the whole environment with no need to split up names.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help.